# Align and Format Multiple Elements Dynamically Added to Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, alignment

I'm trying to make a greasemonkey userscript where I add a div through an ajax request to a table. The table repeats this pattern around 700 times:

```
<table id="table01" >
<tr class = "row0"> 
    <td rowspan = "2" >
        <img src = "url" >
    </td>
    <td> text1 </td>
    <td style = "text-align: right;" > text2 </td>
</tr>
<tr class = "row1">
    <td> text3 </td>
    <td style = "text-align: right;" > text4 </td>
</tr>

...
...
...

</table>
```

I can't manage to insert the div and and set the css alignment to make it look like in the image:
http://s24.postimg.org/wastsl5it/Sin_t_tulo.png
How can I do it using javascript or jquery?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the output here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EzYa/)

My solution is to work with percentages.  The width of the page is 100% percent.  When the elements reach 100% percent, it will force the next element wrap around into a position below.  And use `float`, not `text-align: right`.  I set everything to `float:left`, and set the `width` so that elements will wrap around to the next line.

```
<table id="table01" >
<tr class = "row0"> 
    <div style="width:20%; float:left; border: solid thin purple">
            <img src = "url" >
    </div>

    <div style="width:79%; float:left">
        <div style="width:49%; float:left; border: solid thin"> text1 </div>
        <div style = "width: 49%; float:left; border: solid thin red"> text2 </div>

        <div style="width: 98%; float:left; border: solid thin blue">Center</div>

        <div style = "width: 48%; float:left; border: solid thin green"> text3 </div>
        <div style = "width: 48%; float:left; border: solid thin orange"> text4 </div>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr class = "row0"> 
    <div style="width:20%; float:left">
            <img src = "url" >
    </div>

    <div style="width:80%; float:left">
        <div style="width:50%; float:left"> text1 </div>
        <div style = "width: 50%; float:left" > text2 </div>

        <div style="width: 100%">Center</div>

        <div style = "width: 50%; float:left"> text3 </div>
        <div style = "width: 50%; float:left"> text4 </div>
    </div>
</tr>

</table>
```

Note that the `<div>` you were having trouble with, is set to a width of 100% percent.  So it will take up all of it's section.   Also, realize that the `<div>` set to 100% percent does **NOT** take up 100% percent of the page.  It takes up 100% percent of the `<div>` that it is inside of.  That is the other thing you need to know.  The widths are relative to the element that they are inside of.

With borders added, so you can actually see how everything lays out, the widths need to be smaller, because the borders take up space.  So, 100% width with a border added is more than 100% percent.  So you have to change the width to something smaller, 99% percent maybe.